# Выбор случайного порядка вывода строк без повторений

Tags: python, случайные-числа

У меня есть записанные вопросы, например:

- Почему 2+2 будет 4?
- Почему если не учиться будешь получать плохую оценку?
- Как избежать получение плохих оценок?

Мне нужно обеспечить случайный порядок их вывода, при так, чтобы при этом ни один вопрос не выводился дважды.

Comment: Вопрос такого типа часто повторяется, один из вариантов решения, поместить все вопросы в список (list) перемешать , с помощью random.shuffle(список) , и перебрать список, будет случайный выбор без повторений.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# импортируем 'shuffle' из библиотеки 'random'
from random import shuffle

# создаем список с вопросами
questions = [
    "Почему 2+2 будет 4?",
    "Почему если не учиться будешь получать плохую оценку?",
    "Как избежать получение плохих оценок?",
]

# перемешиваем вопросы в случайном порядке
shuffle(questions)

# проходимся по списку и выводим каждый вопрос
for question in questions:
    print(question)
```

Answer (score 0):

[random.sample](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample):

> Return a k length list of unique elements chosen from the population
> sequence. Used for random sampling without replacement.

Попросите у него выбрать все элементы (`random.sample(questions, len(questions))`):

```
import random


questions = [
    "Почему 2+2 будет 4?",
    "Почему если не учиться будешь получать плохую оценку?",
    "Как избежать получение плохих оценок?",
]
print(*random.sample(questions, len(questions)), sep='\n')
```

> ```
> $ python questions.py
> Почему если не учиться будешь получать плохую оценку?
> Почему 2+2 будет 4?
> Как избежать получение плохих оценок?
>
> $ python questions.py
> Почему 2+2 будет 4?
> Как избежать получение плохих оценок?
> Почему если не учиться будешь получать плохую оценку?
>
> $ python questions.py
> Почему если не учиться будешь получать плохую оценку?
> Как избежать получение плохих оценок?
> Почему 2+2 будет 4?
> ```